Image forward and backward transformations discrepency
Why are images transformed by ImageTransformation always a better quality than by ImageForwardTransformation?
Is it a bug or is it because of different mathematical procedures they use?
I tested many different functions and it is always that ImageTransformation is better.
Image 1 is original. Image 3 is better than image 2 and image 5 is better than image 4.
gr = Graphics[{Table[{If[i == 24 - j, Gray, Black], 
     Disk[{i, j}, 1/4]}, {i, 19}, {j, 13}], 
   Table[{If[i == 23 - j, Gray, Black], {RGBColor[RandomReal[1, {3}]],
       Disk[{i, j} + 1/2, 1/4]}}, {i, 18}, {j, 12}]}]
ImageForwardTransformation[gr, #^(1/2) &]
ImageTransformation[gr, #^2 &]
ImageForwardTransformation[gr, #^2 &]
ImageTransformation[gr, #^(1/2) &]








From the help for ImageForwardTransformation By  default, transformed  points  are  interpolated  using  Method -> "Interpolated" . Whereas the help for ImageTransformation says the Resampling option is Automatic by default, meaning it may be selecting a better method. You don't get much control over the interpolation method of ImageForwardTransformation - it's either Automatic or None, so just stuck with ImageTransformation for better results.

Sometimes it is easier to define a function for ImageForwardTransformation  than for ImageTransformation since it is not always possible to have an inverse function. Also the differences in Method between the two has no sense to me.
